# Facebook Custom Conversions Api Server test event's doesn't show up

Tags: php, curl, facebook-graph-api

i spent a loooot of hours figuring out how to make the "must" changes about facebook custom conversions api to my website to make it work.

Even my console log respond as ok, server's test events are zero.

Please help me to solve tis. Thanks a lot!

I am attaching you my code so far:

```
//LATEST CODE
function getRealIpAddr(){
 if ( !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']) ) {
  // Check IP from internet.
  $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
 } elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']) ) {
  // Check IP is passed from proxy.
  $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
 } else {
  // Get IP address from remote address.
  $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
 }
 return $ip;
}   
    

function get_browser_name($user_agent){
    $t = strtolower($user_agent);
    $t = " " . $t;
    if     (strpos($t, 'opera'     ) || strpos($t, 'opr/')     ) return 'Opera'            ;   
    elseif (strpos($t, 'edge'      )                           ) return 'Edge'             ;   
    elseif (strpos($t, 'chrome'    )                           ) return 'Chrome'           ;   
    elseif (strpos($t, 'safari'    )                           ) return 'Safari'           ;   
    elseif (strpos($t, 'firefox'   )                           ) return 'Firefox'          ;   
    elseif (strpos($t, 'msie'      ) || strpos($t, 'trident/7')) return 'Internet Explorer';
    return 'Unkown';
}
//echo get_browser_name($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);//Chrome
    
    
    
    
    
$data = array( // main object
    
    
    "data" => array( // data array
        
        
        array(
            
            
            
            "event_name" => "Purchase",
            "action_source" => "website",
            "event_source_url"  => "$purl",
            "event_time" => time(),
               "user_data" => array(
                "client_ip_address" => getRealIpAddr(),
                "client_user_agent" => get_browser_name($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']),
                "ph" => $usersmobile,
                ),
                "custom_data" => array(
                "currency" => "EUR",
                "value"    => $product_price,
                ),
       ),
        
        
        
    
    
    
    
    ),
       "access_token" => "ACCESSTOKEN HERE"



);  


$dataString = json_encode($data);                                                                                                              
$ch = curl_init('https://graph.facebook.com/v10.0/PIXELID HERE/events');                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $dataString);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($dataString))                                                                       
);                                                                                                                                                                       
$response = curl_exec($ch);
if ($response){
?>  
    console.log(<?php echo $response; ?>);
    console.log(<?php echo $dataString ?>);
<?
}
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve? @irene-t